# Custom training loop made with tf.Module initialized with zeros doesn't learn

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

My implementation is based on [Tensorflow: custom training walkthrough](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_modules) and [Tensorflow: introduction to modules, layers, and models](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough).

I made a simple neural network with custom built dense layers, almost identical to the tutorials in the links I have linked. The problem is that it won't learn. Where did I go wrong?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

ds = tfds.load('iris', split='train', as_supervised=True)

train_ds = ds.take(125).shuffle(125).batch(1)
test_ds = ds.skip(125).take(25).shuffle(25).batch(1)

class Dense(tf.Module):
  def __init__(self, in_features, out_features, activation, name=None):
    super().__init__(name=name)
    self.activation = activation
    self.w = tf.Variable(
      tf.random.uniform([in_features, out_features]), name='w')
    self.b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([out_features]), name='b')
  def __call__(self, x):
    y = tf.matmul(x, self.w) + self.b
    return self.activation(y)

class SequentialModule(tf.Module):
  def __init__(self, name):
    super().__init__(name=name)
    self.dense1 = Dense(in_features=4, out_features=16, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    self.dense2 = Dense(in_features=16, out_features=32, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    self.dense3 = Dense(in_features=32, out_features=3, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

  def __call__(self, x):
    x = self.dense1(x)
    x = self.dense2(x)
    x = self.dense3(x)
    return x

my_model = SequentialModule(name="model")

loss_object = tf.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy

def compute_loss(model, x, y):
    out = model(x)
    loss = loss_object(y, out, from_logits=False)
    return out, loss

def compute_gradients(model, x, y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        out, loss_value = compute_loss(model, x, y)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
    return out, loss_value, gradients

optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)

for epoch in range(1, 5 + 1):
    train_loss = tf.metrics.Mean(name='train_loss')
    test_loss = tf.metrics.Mean(name='test_loss')

    train_acc = tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()
    test_acc = tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()

    for input_batch, label_batch in train_ds:
        output, loss_value, gradients = compute_gradients(my_model, input_batch, label_batch)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, my_model.trainable_variables))

        train_loss.update_state(loss_value)
        train_acc.update_state(label_batch, output)

    for input_batch, label_batch in test_ds:
        output, loss_value = compute_loss(my_model, input_batch, label_batch)

        test_loss.update_state(loss_value)
        test_acc.update_state(label_batch, output)

    print(f'Epoch {epoch:03d} Loss {train_loss.result():=5.3f} Acc {train_acc.result():=5.3f} '
          f'TLoss {test_loss.result():=5.3f} TAcc {test_acc.result():=5.3f}')
```

```
Epoch 001 Loss 10.445 Acc 0.352 TLoss 12.250 TAcc 0.240
Epoch 002 Loss 10.445 Acc 0.352 TLoss 12.250 TAcc 0.240
Epoch 003 Loss 10.445 Acc 0.352 TLoss 12.250 TAcc 0.240
Epoch 004 Loss 10.445 Acc 0.352 TLoss 12.250 TAcc 0.240
Epoch 005 Loss 10.445 Acc 0.352 TLoss 12.250 TAcc 0.240
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems the problem was purely statistical. As opposed to the tutorial linked, if you use `tf.initializers.GlorotUniform` as initializer, it learns just fine.

```
self.w = tf.Variable(
      tf.initializers.GlorotUniform()([in_features, out_features]), name='w')
```

```
Epoch  1 Loss 0.515 Acc 0.776 TLoss 0.537 TAcc 0.720
Epoch  2 Loss 0.186 Acc 0.928 TLoss 0.136 TAcc 0.920
Epoch  3 Loss 0.171 Acc 0.944 TLoss 0.104 TAcc 0.920
Epoch  4 Loss 0.230 Acc 0.920 TLoss 0.268 TAcc 0.880
Epoch  5 Loss 0.177 Acc 0.928 TLoss 0.284 TAcc 0.880
Epoch  6 Loss 0.144 Acc 0.944 TLoss 0.111 TAcc 0.920
Epoch  7 Loss 0.151 Acc 0.952 TLoss 0.137 TAcc 0.920
Epoch  8 Loss 0.192 Acc 0.952 TLoss 0.111 TAcc 0.960
Epoch  9 Loss 0.081 Acc 0.968 TLoss 0.074 TAcc 0.960
Epoch 10 Loss 0.222 Acc 0.920 TLoss 0.097 TAcc 1.000
```